# How to convert from image url like 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png' to base64 string in ionic3?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting image url from server.I need post the image to server.So I need to convert image url to base64 string in Ionic 3 for database storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you [google "js image url to base64"](http://www.google.com/search?q=js%20image%20url%20to%20base64) you will find many implementations.

Example:

```js
/**
 * Convert an image 
 * to a base64 url
 * @param  {String}   url         
 * @param  {Function} callback    
 * @param  {String}   [outputFormat=image/png]           
 */
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/CawaKharkov/1c477d44fcfdf67aea3f